# Ruby on Rails - MiniMagick - resize image only if it has specific format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minimagick

I'm trying to create MiniMagick image uploader, that allow svg files, but not resize it. Now I'm stuck with 'undefined method `resize_img' for MyImageUploader:Class' with this code:

```
class MyImageUploader < BaseImageUploader

  def resize_img
    puts 'method init'
    unless self.blank?
      puts 'not blank!'
      image = MiniMagick::Image::open self.current_path
      unless image.format == 'svg'
        process resize_to_limit: [100, 100]
      end
    end
  end

  self.resize_img

end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change `self.resize_img` to `resize_img`

Comment: @Sajin got return with 'undefined local variable or method `resize_img' for PartnerImageUploader:Class'

Comment: Which file upload gem are you using?

Comment: @AmitPatel carrierwave 1.0.0

Comment: Check the example http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave/MiniMagick

Comment: Also https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to:-do-conditional-processing this would help

Comment: You are calling `resize_image` on `myImageUploader` and not on a instance of this class.